# How Cognito verifies password?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I can create a user in AWS users pool using

```
module.exports.signup = function(req, res, next) {
    let attributeList = [];
    let dataEmail = {
        Name : 'email',
        Value : req.body.username
    };

    let attributeEmail = new CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);

    attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
    userPool.signUp(req.body.username, req.body.password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Sigup failure:',err);
            res.status(403).send(err.message);
        }
        let cognitoUser = result.user;
        res.status(200).send({ "user": cognitoUser.getUsername() });
    });
}
```

but it seems the password is not stored in the user pool in any way. It's implied it should be stored somewhere else and then being retrieved from there. What is the easiest or the most common way to store and verify password on AWS? 
After I sign up I can't sign in (assume because of the password storage issue). Gets "Incorrect username or password" error in return.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito will not allow you to see stored passwords, it is part security. You can [authenticate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-user) a user using the javascript SDK like this:

```
    var authenticationData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Password : 'password',
};
var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_TcoKGbf7n',
    ClientId : '4pe2usejqcdmhi0a25jp4b5sh3'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
var userData = {
    Username : 'username',
    Pool : userPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();

        /* Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with identity pools or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
        var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
    },

    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },

});
```

Comment: ye I've read the doc and have a version of the mentioned code on my side. The point is, it's not enough. I'm getting "incorrect username or password"

Comment: Check if you are sending the correct username and password. Write a separate authenticateuser function and pass username and password as strings. See if you are still getting error